# Mass of spring in damped harmonic motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

In my textbook, the equations for damped harmonic motion seem to neglect the mass of the spring. What would the equations look like if we actually included the mass of the spring? For example, we have the following:

[image]

which leads to

[image]

and

[image]

How would you account for the mass of the spring? Do we just simply add it  into the equation (that is, we say that m = mass of oscillator + mass of spring ?

Comment: [Effective mass (spring–mass system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_\(spring%E2%80%93mass_system\)).

Comment: I read the wikipedia page, but they show what the equations would look like if a mass is oscillating in simple harmonic motion. I'm looking for the damped motion equations.

Comment: You put the damping constant into the same equation, but you use the effective mass instead of the mass of the block.

Comment: So if M= mass of the block and m(s)= mass of the spring, then we can say that m in the formula from my post is the following: m = M+ m(f)/3

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of levels of accuracy with which this can be done. The most accurate way is to treat the spring continuously (even if not as a helical coil). This requires a description of a continuous body though, so something like strain and displacement. In this case, the spring itself does not have a single displacement, but waves in it. The answer will generally be Fourier series. In this case, you can also get rid of the mass, $m$, and just look at the free spring vibrating. If you leave the point mass in, it is a part of one of the boundary conditions.

It would be very difficult, but you could actually model the spring as a coil if desired. Then you would have torsion waves too.

If you want to keep it as a single point variable (just the location $x$), you can make an assumption that the spring deforms the same everywhere. Then, the motion of the mass center of the spring is well defined. The motion of the system mass center will depend on the ratios of the mass $m$ and the spring mass and spring length. With the mass nature of the system defined, Rayleigh's energy method can be used as an estimate of the natural frequency.

The rough way to understand this method is to equate maximum kinetic energy with maximum potential energy. The potential energy is a function of the amplitude, and other factors which in this case is just half the stiffness. The kinetic energy is a function of the speed, which is amplitude times frequency, and other factors which in this case are half the total mass times the factor connecting amplitude of the motion of the end to the motion of the system mass center. The total amplitude of vibration divides out, and the frequency is known as a function of system properties.